# Do I need a regex to determine if a url is a dynamic url?

Tags: python, regex, url, dynamic-url

I want to create a function to determine if a well-formed url was dynamically generated (according to this article https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/D/dynamic_URL.html)

My first attempt was to check if any of these characters appear in the url:

ex:

```
def is_dynamic_url(url):
    for ch in ["?", "&", "%", "+", "=", "$", "cgi-bin", ".cgi"]:
        if ch in url:
            return True
```

Is this sufficient or are there edge cases I am not considering?

Comment: *Every* URL can be a dynamic URL.  Just take a look at the URL for this page — it contains none of those strings, yet the contents still change based on queries to the site's database.

Comment: The URL for *this page*, with your question, is dynamically generated. I can trivially create a static website that'll contain those characters and is **not dynamic**. The article there is, at best *very, very outdated*.

Comment: What is described there was perhaps once true in the 1990s somewhere, if only as a gross simplification and rough rule of thumb. It is not true today.

Comment: You cannot know from a URL alone whether it was generated by a query from a database. The referenced article is giving you some clues to guess whether it is, but static pages can have such URLs, and dynamic pages can avoid them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters
Thanks for the heads up.
What would be a better heuristic to determine if a URL corresponds to a dynamically-generated page?

Comment: @HanBonsen: **any** URL can correspond to a dynamically generated page. There is no possible heuristic.

Comment: @MartijnPieters

Is this true even if I attempt to download the contents of the page and check it? Sorry for my ignorance, not really too knowledgeable about web development. Is there anything in the header/body of a page that gives it away as a dynamically generated page?

Comment: What you have been told is true, a URL can point to static or dynamic resources no matter its shape. That said, there are heuristics you could apply, even though they are fallible. For example, if you are not using cookies and the [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) header (or [equivalent `meta` HTML header](https://www.metatags.org/meta_http_equiv_cache_control)) has long expiration time it's likely to be static. But not necessarily, and not all servers will set the headers right.

Comment: [`Expires`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires) is another HTTP header you could consider.

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find an example of a page that uses these headers (including this stack overflow) page. I'll add some code to my application just in case.

Comment: @HanBonsen: the contents of a web page are the *result* of a dynamic or static URL. The same goes for all the other information in the response. You are simply looking at the product of a HTTP server. How the HTTP server constructed that response is a black box and can't be classifed as 'static' or dynamic' with any degree of certainty.

Comment: @jdehesa: I've build tons of web applications that made use of long cache expiration configurations. Just because a resource is created dynamically doesn't mean it shouldn't be cacheable. The majority of sites that minify and combine their JS resources are effectively generating the contents of those responses dynamically but then use cache headers and forwarding proxies to cache the result for long periods of time.

Comment: @HanBonsen Well, these Stack Overflow pages are not static, but images, CSS, JS, etc. in pages typically are, or, maybe better, "behave as static resources", since, as Martijn says, what you see is simply what the server decides to produce on each request.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I understand that, I was thinking of the looser notion of "content that behaves as a static resource", as I put in my previous comment. The truth is that very few URLs, if any (relevant, I mean), will direct you to a bare server that responds with some content stored in disk (if that is how one would define static resources)...

Comment: @jdehesa: and therein lies another big problem: the term 'dynamic' is too broad and not so easily pinned down as that page makes it sound like. *Every* HTTP response is dynamic, in that the server usually includes a [`Date` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date) with the server time. Can the server clock be considered a database? Can its configuration file that maps paths to directory locations, or the mime-type mapping that configures what to set the Content-Type header to? There is enough grey area here to drive several nerd-sniping trucks through.

Answer (score 2):

You can't determine if a URL is 'dynamic' from the characters in the string. Web servers have moved way beyond CGI scripts served from a hard-coded URL path. Even when the article was current, it was never more than a weak heuristic.

A URL is simply an *address* for a resource; the [acronym stands for *Universal Resource Locator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL). When the URL starts with `http:` or `https:`, you have a URL for a web page, but URLs can address far more than just web pages.

For the type of URLs that article talks about, a client (your browser, say) will use the first portion, between `//` and `/` to connect to a specific server to exchange messages using the [HTTP standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). The client sends everything after the host information (the *path* component) to the server. For this question. the full URL shown in the browser is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230441/do-i-need-a-regex-to-determine-if-a-url-is-a-dynamic-url`, so the browser uses an encrypted connection to the server named `stackoverflow.com`, and sends it a request to serve the `/questions/53230441/do-i-need-a-regex-to-determine-if-a-url-is-a-dynamic-url` path.

How the server responds is **entirely up to the server**. A HTTP server is essentially a black box in this exchange. It can do whatever it likes with the information, and within the broad confines of the HTTP standard, it can produce a response by any means it likes.

In the very early days of the web, the HTTP server would only ever map the path given directly to a filesystem. For example, based on the server configuration the path `/foo/bar/baz.html` would be mapped to the filename `/var/data/www/foo/bar/baz.html` file, and if it existed the server would read the contents of that file and return those contents back to the client together some metadata, and that was it. If you wanted to customise this process, you either wrote your own HTTP server or used some kind of extension mechanism specific to the web server. The NCSA web server had a different mechanism from the Netscape server which differed from the Apache HTTP server, etc. Not many sites needed this kind of processing, computers powerful enough to run databases were expensive, and programming such exotic behaviour took a lot of time and specialist knowledge.

Then the NCSA HTTP server implementation created a standard for delegating a HTTP request to arbitrary programs (such as scripts), called the [Common Gateway Interface, or *CGI*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface), and because everything was still centered on mapping URL paths to files, web site administrators were expected to put CGI programs in a dedicated directory, usually named CGI-bin. A path starting with that name would then be mapped to such a configured location and instead of *reading* files found there and serving them back, the file would instead be executed and the result that the file produced was passed back. For a while that was the most common way to build a website that didn't consist of *just* static files.

And to let you pass information from the client to the server, the most common way to configure a CGI program is to use additional information in the URL, such as the query string (the part starting at `?` if there is one). The standard HTTP server of yore did not let you alter the URL path for a CGI script much, but would pass through the query string unaltered. So adding `?foo=1&bar=2` is a good way to configure such a script.

And that's the kind of URL that article refers to; it gives you a simple *heuristic* for judging if a URL might map to a CGI script and so might be called *dynamic*. It was never meant to be a hard and fast rule that you can teach a computer to look for though.

These days, we have moved far, far beyond CGI scripts. Modern HTTP web servers make it really easy to map *every request, regardless of path* to a (set) of long-running processes, or are themselves directly handling requests via embedded programming language support. For example, Stack Overflow itself is built using the [ASP.NET framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET), which runs directly in the Microsoft IIS HTTP server. Every page you see on this site is 'dynamic' in that it shows you information that is combined from different sources (databases, configuration files, templates stored on disk, etc.). The `/questions/53230441/do-i-need-a-regex-to-determine-if-a-url-is-a-dynamic-url` path is dissected by the Stack Overflow application map to dedicated pieces of code configured to handle patterns in the URL. A path that starts with `/questions/` and a series of digits, followed by `/` and more text, results in database queries for information on the question with number 53230441.

It's trivial these days to build such a site yourself. Take a look at a simple web framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/) for example. With Python and the Flask library installed, I can put

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<name>')
def hello_world(name='World'):
    return f'Hello, {name}!'
```

into a file named `site.py`, execute the command `FLASK_APP=site flask run` and point my browser to the URL `http://localhost:5000/` and see the text `Hello, World!` appear, or load `http://localhost:5000/Han` instead and see `Hello, Han!` in the browser. Those are dynamic URLs too!

Note: I haven't even touched on using JavaScript in the web browser here, which adds a whole new level of dynamism, where the *client* is now smart and can change the behaviour of web pages, load additional URLs in the background and keep changing web page content all the time.

All this means that you can’t tell much, if anything, from just the characters in a URL anymore as to what it’ll produce or if that result was built ”dynamically”.